# How to do simple DOM Manipuation in React + ES6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

All I want to do is change the header text on a button click.

Here's what I have so far (does not work, there are no console errors)

```
class Test extends React.Component {
    click() {
        $(".update").val("new value")
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <h3 className="update">Old value</h3>
          <button onClick={this.click}>update!</button>
        </div>
      );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be displaying data from either your component state or props passed down to it from a parent, **not** manipulating the DOM directly. I'd suggest checking out the [Component API](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html) to get a better understanding of how things like `setState` work. Here is a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/29886/)

```
class Test extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {value: 'Old Value'}
      this.click = this.click.bind(this)
    }

    click() {
       this.setState({value: 'new value'})
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <h3 className="update">{this.state.value}</h3>
          <button onClick={this.click}>update!</button>
        </div>
      );
    }
}
```

Note that I am using ES6 as you have in your example - that is why I am manually binding `this` to that function. In ES6, you do not have to bind `this` to the React default functions such as `render()` and `componentDidMount()` but for anything custom you will have to.

Comment: Why did you have to use super(props)? Edit : I think I got it, super() is what will call the React.Component constructor and make this class a react component

Comment: Yes, `super()` is for ES6 class constructors and because this is extending the `React.Component` class, adding `super(props)` says to pass down any properties from its parent class. Read this for a better understanding of ES6 class notation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: If you're curious about binding `this` like I did, there are a few ways you could do that actually and it also varies on whether or not you are using ES5, ES6, or ES7. This is a nice reference for that: http://egorsmirnov.me/2015/08/16/react-and-es6-part3.html

Answer (score 1):

For starters, the value of a button does not do what you're thinking it does. You probably want to use `.text` to change the text on the button. Also, what do you mean by "not working"?

The whole point of React is not to use jquery for DOM manipulations. You should instead be using the state or props to do that. For example:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3 className="update">Old value</h3>
      <button onClick={this.setState({buttonText:'something else'})}>
        {this.state.buttonText}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Zeke, obviously I am new at React and am still trying to understand it.  I was not aware of the buttonText attribute of setState. Is there a documentation that lists what else I can pass into setState?

Comment: @user2202911: You can pass anything. What to keep in the state is specific to your component. If you haven't read the React documentation, you should: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html, https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html .